# vue nested for loop for checkbox-groups

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, v-for

i have this obj here:

```js
      rightGroups: [
        {
          name: "Rechte für die Administration",
          id: 1,
          rights: [
            {
              caption: 'Rechte verwalten',
              name: 'reports',
              right: false,
              id: 1
            },
            {
              caption: 'Rechte X',
              name: 'admin.rightX',
              right: false,
              id: 2
            },
            {
              caption: 'Rechte Y',
              name: 'admin.rightY',
              right: false,
              id: 3
            },
            {
              caption: 'Rechte Z',
              name: 'admin.rightZ',
              right: false,
              id: 4
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          name: "Rechte für die Benutzerverwaltung",
          id: 2,
          rights: [
            {
              caption: 'Benutzer verwalten',
              name: 'user.recht',
              right: false,
              id: 1
            },
            {
              caption: 'Recht X',
              name: 'user.rightX',
              right: false,
              id: 2
            },
            {
              caption: 'Recht Y',
              name: 'user.rightY',
              right: false,
              id: 3
            },
            {
              caption: 'Recht Z',
              name: 'user.rightZ',
              right: false,
              id: 4
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
```

which should only display dynamic loaded checkbox groups like this:
[checkbox groups](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTEEF.jpg)

each checkbox-group should have there very own checkboxes loaded only.
i try to acomplish this with a v-for in bootstrap-vue like this:

```html
    <b-row class="mt-5">
      <b-col
        v-for="group in rightGroups"
        :key="group.id"
        md="6"
      >
        <b-card
          border-variant="dark"
        >
          <template v-slot:header>
            <b-form-checkbox>
              <strong>{{ group.name }}</strong>
            </b-form-checkbox>
          </template>

          <b-form-checkbox
            v-for="right in group"
            :key="right.id"
          >

          </b-form-checkbox>
        </b-card>
      </b-col>

    </b-row>
```

i only want the rights loaded in there very own groups. how can i do this?

i created a codesandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-snowflake-2q4l0?file=/src/components/Rights.vue

Answer (score 0):

Is this is what you are looking for? Just replace the below code in your CSB Rights.vue file to see the changes.

```
<template>
  <div id="authorization">
    <b-row class="m-5">
      <b-col v-for="group in rightGroups" :key="group.id" md="6" align="start">
        <b-card border-variant="dark">
          <template v-slot:header>
            <b-form-checkbox>
              <strong>{{ group.name }}</strong>
            </b-form-checkbox>
          </template>

          <b-form-checkbox v-for="rights in group.rights" 
          :key="rights.id" 
          v-model="rights.right">{{rights.caption}}</b-form-checkbox>
        </b-card>
      </b-col>
    </b-row>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      rightGroups: [
        {
          name: "Rechte für die Administration",
          id: 1,
          rights: [
            {
              caption: "Rechte verwalten",
              name: "reports",
              right: true,
              id: 1
            },
            {
              caption: "Rechte X",
              name: "admin.rightX",
              right: false,
              id: 2
            },
            {
              caption: "Rechte Y",
              name: "admin.rightY",
              right: false,
              id: 3
            },
            {
              caption: "Rechte Z",
              name: "admin.rightZ",
              right: false,
              id: 4
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          name: "Rechte für die Benutzerverwaltung",
          id: 2,
          rights: [
            {
              caption: "Benutzer verwalten",
              name: "user.recht",
              right: false,
              id: 1
            },
            {
              caption: "Recht X",
              name: "user.rightX",
              right: false,
              id: 2
            },
            {
              caption: "Recht Y",
              name: "user.rightY",
              right: false,
              id: 3
            },
            {
              caption: "Recht Z",
              name: "user.rightZ",
              right: false,
              id: 4
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should just change the second loop like this :

```
<b-form-checkbox v-for="right in group.rights" :key="right.id">{{right.name}}</b-form-checkbox>
```

This will be good..